# Averiguar si un div esta lleno

Tags: html

Por curiosidad Como se puede determinar si un div esta lleno?

**Ejemplo de lleno**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen anterior muestra un div lleno, por que no hay espacio para seguir escribiendo, la palabra **hola** completo el limite del `div`.

**Ejemplo de que no esta lleno**(por que aun tiene espacio abajo para seguir escribiendo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lleno  != no esta vacio

Como dice @A.Cedano "determinar si esta lleno depende de varios factores como el tamaño de letra".

Este ejemplo puede ayudar? http://jsfiddle.net/yfSUk/3

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Si a tu primer div le pones un tamaño de letra más pequeño seguro que deja de estar *lleno*  según tu concepto. Explica por favor qué es lo que define la *llenitud*  de tu div. Creo que estamos ante un problema más complejo que la teoría de la relatividad.

Comment: @A.Cedano  no puse codigo por que no se como afrontar este problema por que depende del tamaño de letra, si se escribe al final directamente, etc, por esa razon hice mi pregunta.

Comment: Ya, pero es que como está planteada la pregunta actualmente es imposible. Yo mismo cuando la leí pensé que querías saber si el `div` no tenía nada. Para hacer esto que quieres es algo difícil ya que incluso a veces el div se puede *llenar*  o no según qué caracteres sean. Por ejemplo la `l` en algunos escenarios ocupa menos espacio que la `a` o la `p`. A veces te caben 50 `l` y solamente 43 `a`. Lo mismo pasa con los números, que el `1` ocupa menos espacio en la pantalla que el `0` o el `4` ...

Comment: @A.Cedano por eso mismo anteriormente puse este link http://jsfiddle.net/yfSUk/3 que creo que ayudaria

Comment: @x-rw no soy experto en el tema pero probablemente tu pregunta podrias ser más clara si explicas porque quieres esa funcionalidad. Quizas este sea un problema XY

Comment: @eyllanesc en realidad no lo necesito, solo me surgio la duda del calculo o algun artificio para encontrar la solucion

Comment: @x-rw seria bueno que indiques ello, es decir que es por pura curiosidad, a veces no existe la solucion en este tipo de problemas, o la solución es demasiado *pesada* (es decir es impractica) por lo que nunca se aplicara.

Comment: @eyllanesc puse un link, en un inicio pense que seria una buena base

Comment: tendrías que usar un div clon oculto para chequear si se pasa del tamaño asignado

Comment: [Esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/127920/mostrar-alerta-cuando-texto-necesite-overflow) puede estar relacionada

Comment: La verdad no terminé de entender la pregunta y "aún cuando has aceptado una respuesta", te pregunto: ¿intentase usar `document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML.length`?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave se refiere a si el contenido del div "llena" el espacio disponible (dado por los límites implícitos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí uso un contenedor para evitar que el code snippet interfiera, la onda es chequear el `clientHeight` contra el `scrollHeight`.

En el caso del div uno es visible, en el caso del div tres está oculto por un contenedor

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let losDivs = [...document.getElementsByClassName("trackme")];

  losDivs.forEach(function(element) {

    console.log(element.id, element.clientHeight, element.scrollHeight);
    if (element.clientHeight < element.scrollHeight) {
      element.style.background = "#fe0";
      console.log(element.id, "se pasa de texto");
    }
  });


});
```

```css
.contenedor div {
  width: 640px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.oculta {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div id="uno" class="trackme"><b>UNO</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vel pharetra diam. Cras nisi leo, lobortis non lorem non, suscipit aliquam felis. Duis posuere laoreet eros, vel efficitur sem aliquet ac. Ut sit amet lectus rhoncus felis pharetra
    euismod sed at dolor. Praesent quis lectus id enim facilisis finibus et nec leo. Vestibulum a lacus arcu. Praesent a fringilla ligula, a facilisis neque. Phasellus vitae efficitur lectus. Duis volutpat scelerisque ipsum non faucibus. Ut scelerisque
    ex eget rutrum bibendum. Nulla malesuada lacus eu felis porta molestie. Sed tincidunt arcu lorem, et porttitor odio dictum nec. Morbi rutrum tellus ornare, pulvinar sem vitae, rutrum magna. Curabitur vel rutrum sapien. Integer scelerisque tellus odio,
    sit amet tincidunt lorem accumsan ut.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="contenedor">
  <div id="dos" class="trackme"><b>DOS</b> Curabitur ornare ligula id laoreet tempor. Aliquam nisi justo, blandit id massa nec, pharetra vehicula est. Nunc et velit eu mi facilisis tempor id ac mauris. Sed non lacinia eros. Fusce orci tortor, consectetur a erat et, dignissim rhoncus
    felis. Suspendisse id tempor lorem, et vulputate tortor. Donec ac condimentum odio. Sed porta id nisi vitae malesuada. Sed ultricies, odio quis hendrerit hendrerit, eros magna interdum nulla, sed bibendum tellus nunc sit amet nibh.</div>
</div>
<div class="contenedor oculta">
  <div id="tres" class="trackme"><b>TRES</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vel pharetra diam. Cras nisi leo, lobortis non lorem non, suscipit aliquam felis. Duis posuere laoreet eros, vel efficitur sem aliquet ac. Ut sit amet lectus rhoncus felis pharetra
    euismod sed at dolor. Praesent quis lectus id enim facilisis finibus et nec leo. Vestibulum a lacus arcu. Praesent a fringilla ligula, a facilisis neque. Phasellus vitae efficitur lectus. Duis volutpat scelerisque ipsum non faucibus. Ut scelerisque
    ex eget rutrum bibendum. Nulla malesuada lacus eu felis porta molestie. Sed tincidunt arcu lorem, et porttitor odio dictum nec. Morbi rutrum tellus ornare, pulvinar sem vitae, rutrum magna. Curabitur vel rutrum sapien. Integer scelerisque tellus odio,
    sit amet tincidunt lorem accumsan ut.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: si me parece acertada tu respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Una cosa que podrías hacer es crear un clon del elemento, añadirle un carácter, y comprobar si la altura del elemento ha cambiado. Si cambió quiere decir que estaba lleno y no admitía más. Si la altura es la misma, quiere decir que aún tenía espacio para más texto.

Para ello puedes crear una función como ésta:

```
function comprobarLleno(selector) {
  // seleccionamos el original y creamos un clon
  var original = document.querySelector(selector);
  var copia = original.cloneNode(true);

  // le añadimos un carácter (por ejemplo, un punto) y lo escondemos con CSS
  copia.innerHTML += ".";
  copia.style.visibility = "hidden";
  copia.style.overflow = "auto";

  // añadimos el clon al documento
  document.querySelector("body").append(copia);

  // comparamos las alturas de clon y original
  if (copia.scrollHeight > original.scrollHeight) {
    // si la altura del clon es mayor, el elemento original estaba lleno
    console.log(`El elemento ${selector} está lleno`);
  } else {
    // la altura del clon es igual a la del elemento original que no estaba lleno
    console.log(`El elemento ${selector} NO está lleno`);
  }

  // eliminamos el clon
  copia.remove();
}
```

Y aquí la puedes ver funcionando:

```js
function comprobarLleno(selector) {
  var original = document.querySelector(selector);
  var copia = original.cloneNode(true);
  copia.innerHTML += ".";
  copia.style.visibility = "hidden";
  copia.style.overflow = "auto";
  document.querySelector("body").append(copia);
  if (copia.scrollHeight > original.scrollHeight) {
    console.log(`El elemento ${selector} está lleno`);
  } else {
    console.log(`El elemento ${selector} NO está lleno`);
  }
  copia.remove();
}

comprobarLleno("#tarjeta-1");
comprobarLleno("#tarjeta-2");
```

```css
.tarjeta {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border:1px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tarjeta" id="tarjeta-1">
  En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme...
</div>

<div class="tarjeta" id="tarjeta-2">
  En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los de lanza en astillero, adarga antigua, rocín...
</div>
```

Comment: tambien esta respuesta responde a mi pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

En jQuery puedes usar el selecto **[`empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)** del siguiente modo, sabiendo que por *estar lleno* se entiende tener algo, aunque sea un espacio en blanco.

```js
var divStatus = "";
var divID = "";
$("div").each(function() {
  divID = $(this).prop('id');
  divStatus = ($(this).is(':empty')) ? "Vacío" : "Lleno";
  console.log(`El div ${divID} está: ${divStatus}`);
});
```

```css
.my-div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}

.vacio {
  background-color: blue;
}

.lleno {
  background-color: red;
}

.enblanco {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-div lleno" id="lleno">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<br />
<div class="my-div vacio" id="vacio"></div>
<br />
<div class="my-div enblanco" id="enblanco"> </div>
```

Comment: puse ejemplos de cuando un div esta lleno, revisa mi pregunta porfavor

Comment: @x-rw explica *textualmente*  tu concepto de ***lleno*** porque viendo las imágenes no lo entiendo. Eso de que *aún tiene espacio*  ¿qué quiere decir exactamente? En teoría un div siempre va a tener espacio.

Answer (score -1):

Si un div está lleno? La función que posteaste no tiene nada que ver con lo que preguntas, te invito a arreglar tu pregunta o de lo contrario esta es la respuesta.

Utiliza el método `.html()` de jquery para traer lo que tiene dentro un selector.

Saludos

```js
//Función cuando este listo el DOM
$(function(){

//Evento cuando le den click al div
$(document).on('click','div',function(){
  
  //Con una condicional ternaria validar si el div está lleno.
  let msg = $(this).html() === '' ? 'Está vacío': 'No está vacío';
  alert(msg);
});

});
```

```css
div{
height:200px;
width:49%;
color:red;
background-color:aliceblue;
float:left;
margin:0.5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div><p>WTF</p></div>
```

Comment: actualice mi pregunta

Comment: Pues el ejemplo no tiene nada que ver con lo que estás buscando, la solución es más sencilla de lo que piensas... Te puse la respuesta

Comment: es que si hay espacio en un div eso quiere decir que aun no esta lleno